# Submitting pyspark job with zip file

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have four  python files , out of four files 1 file has spark entry code defined and that file drives and calls rest other python files .
for now I have provided four python files with --py-files option in spark submit command , but instead of submitting this way I want to create zip file and pack these all four python files and submit with spark-submit .
though I tried to search a bit and came to know i can create zip file let's say myfile.zip and pack all four python files into this zip file and submit spark job with --py-file myfile.zip . But with this approach I have also seen in multiple places I need to add one line of code sc.addfile(ziplfilepath) in main python file.
if I need to add sc.addfile() , in this case I do not want to provide any path to the program that is reason I am submitting job mentioning all files instead zip file .
my question is :
is it require to add sc.addfile() function and provide path of zip file or while submitting job with --py-file myfile.zip will alone work .

spark submit command I am using now:

```
'Args': ['spark-submit',
                         '--deploy-mode', 'cluster', '--master', 'yarn','--executor-memory',conf['emr_step_executor_memory'], '--executor-cores',conf['emr_step_executor_cores'],
                         '--conf','spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=true','--conf',
                         'spark.rpc.message.maxSize=1024',
                       '--py-files',
                         f'{s3_path}/file2.py,
                         {s3_path}/file3.py,
                         {s3_path}/file4.py',
                         {s3_path}/mainfile.py
                         ]
```

spark-submit command with zip:

```
'Args': ['spark-submit',
                         '--deploy-mode', 'cluster', '--master', 'yarn','--executor-memory',conf['emr_step_executor_memory'], '--executor-cores',conf['emr_step_executor_cores'],
                         '--conf','spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=true','--conf',
                         'spark.rpc.message.maxSize=1024',
                       '--py-files',
                         f'{s3_path}/myzipfile.zip,
                        
                         f'{s3_path}/mainfile.py
                         ]
```

would above spark submit command work if in mainfile.py I do not add sc.addfile() function ?

Comment: As mentioned in previous answer, `addPyFile()` is required as it loads the files to the execution environment. So, I think it wont work and you will need to pass them individually like in first option.

Answer (score -1):

If you are specifically specifying zip file using --py-files then you don't have to specify in program.

Please refer
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#bundling-your-applications-dependencies

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32588432)